# Añadir mi clase de css en php

Tags: php, css

Tengo una duda. En mi HTML tengo una clase que me funciona perfectamente dentro de mi HTML pero cuando inserto esa clase dentro de un while en php no me sale el mismo formato:

El código es el siguiente:

DIV:

```
<div class="hijo" onclick="location.href='libros/don-quijote-de-la-mancha.php';">
                        <h6>Don Quijote de la Mancha</h6>
                        <cite>Miguel de Cervantes</cite>
                </div>
```

Mi PHP:

```
<?php

                    $sql = "SELECT Nombre_libro, Nombre_libro_php FROM libros";
                    $result=query($sql);
                    confirm ($result);  

                    $counter = 0; $rep = 1;
                    echo "<ul>"; 

                    while($row = fetch_array($result)){

                    $folder='/weblibros/libros/';
                    $titulo=$row['Nombre_libro']; 
                    $ruta=$row['Nombre_libro_php'];                     
                    $url = $folder . $ruta;
                    $href="<a href=\"$url\">$titulo</a>"; 
                

                     $counter++; 
                     if ($counter == $rep) { echo "</ul><ul>"; $counter= 0; }


                    if(login_in()) {
                            
                    echo "
                    <div class="/hijo/"> 
                            <h6>$parm1</h6>
                            <cite>$param2</cite>
                    </div>";


                    } else{

                    echo $titulo.'<hr>';

    
            }

        }


?>
```

¿Alguien me podría ayudar?

Gracias!

Comment: Las comillas se escapan `\"` no `"/`. Es decir, deberías poner `class=\"hijo\"`, no `class="/hijo/"`. Pero vamos, que viendo el html que te genera eso deberías darte cuenta de que está mal, porque te aparecerán las `/`. De hecho... lo has usado bien un poco más arriba (`$href="<a href=\"$url\">`), no entiendo por qué aquí lo usas diferente.

Comment: Gracias por responder. He probado lo que me dices y sigue igual . Lo que me da la impresión es que no llega el segundo  if(login_in()) {. Lo he cambiado por un else if pero ahora no me sale nada

Comment: Verás... esas cosas no podemos verlas nosotros. Yo solo veo tu código y tu pregunta. En tu pregunta afirmas que no te sale el mismo formato, así que asumo que al menos lo está imprimiendo... ahora dices que ni siquiera entra al `if`... por qué no debugas y miras qué es exactamente lo que está pasando? Porque si no no hay manera de poder ayudarte. Si no entra al if, obviamente tu pregunta no tiene sentido, principalmente porque ese método ni siquiera existe en el código que nos proporcionas. Además... usas variables que no existen ($parm1, $param2, dónde están declaradas???).

Comment: Hola, gracias. Si, tienes razón, es que como soy un poco nueva en esto de php no se muy bien como explicar mi problema, que no es uno...

Comment: Aun no le encuentro el sentido al if para imprimir el UL, si va a quedar inconsistente, en la ultima iteración del while, no va a imprimir el </ul>, quedará la etiqueta abierta, mas abajo propuse una solución, intentaste con eso?

Answer (score 0):

es que como soy un poco nueva en esto de php no se muy bien como explicar mi problema, que no es uno. He modificado lo de parm1 y param2 poniéndole los parámetros reales. Y ahora ya me aparece el formato. Lo que ocurre es que no me mete la clase por cada valor del array, solo la misma clase para todos y la visualización no es buena. Te paso el codigo modificado:

```
<?php
                $sql = "SELECT Nombre_libro, Nombre_libro_php FROM libros";
                $result=query($sql);
                confirm ($result);  

                

                while($row = fetch_array($result)){

                $folder='/webalejandria/libros/';
                $titulo=$row['Nombre_libro']; 
                $ruta=$row['Nombre_libro_php'];                     
                $url = $folder . $ruta;
                $href="<a href=\"$url\">$titulo</a>"; 
            
                $counter = 0; $rep = 1;
                echo "<ul>"; 


                $counter++; 
                if ($counter != $rep) { echo "</ul><ul>"; $counter= 0; }


                else if(login_in()) {
                        
                echo "
                <div class=\"hijo\">
                        <h6>$href.'<hr>'</h6>
                   </div>";


                } else{

                 echo "
                <div class=\"hijo\">
                        <h6>$titulo.</h6>
                   </div>";


        }

    }


?>
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!

Comment: Por favor, no *respondas* con más datos de la pregunta, utiliza el botón editar que aparece debajo de tu pregunta inicial para modificarla. Esto debe ser una respuesta... pero no responde nada :)

Comment: Una buena práctica es mirar la salida de este codigo, es decir, miras el codigo fuente (html) de la pagina resultante, y ahi probablemente veas que la evaluacion que cierre los UL nunca se cumple, al menos eso me parece, de todas formas me parece una evaluacion innecesaria, ya que en cada iteracion del bucle podes abrir el UL, y luego cerrar el UL al final, no entiendo para que hacer una evaluacion antes.

Comment: Era _editar la pregunta_, no cambiarle completamente el sentido...

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda! Me funciona a la perfección.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no es necesaria la evaluacion de apertura y cierre de etiquetas UL, puesto que en algunas iteraciones no mostrarías la informacion del fetch_array, ademas nunca se cumple, porque en cada iteracion seteas el valor de las variables $counter y $rep, y nunca se cumple la condicion de que $counter != $rep

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT Nombre_libro, Nombre_libro_php FROM libros";
$result=query($sql);
confirm($result);

while ($row = fetch_array($result)) {
    $folder='/webalejandria/libros/';
    $titulo=$row['Nombre_libro'];
    $ruta=$row['Nombre_libro_php'];
    $url = $folder . $ruta;
    $href="<a href=\"$url\">$titulo</a>";

    echo "<ul>";
    if (login_in()) {
        echo "<div class=\"hijo\">
        <h6>$href.'<hr>'</h6>
        </div>";
    } else {
        echo "  <div class=\"hijo\">
        <h6>$titulo.</h6>
        </div>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```